# C++ libcurl to check if remote file is different

Tags: c++, http, libcurl

I was wondering if it's possible to query a file on a remote server before having to download it to know if it's different from a local one.

For example a very large xml file on an HTTP request, if I could see if it's changed without downloading it first I could save a lot of wasted downloading.

Edit: This could be modified date, file size etc

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You can run a HEAD request to just get header information. Depending on the server these might even contain a Header Field with the checksum of the file (though it is unlikely).
Looking for the "Last-Modified" Header field, as Aleksandar pointed out, is a good start.
Look here for information how to get only the header with libcurl:
[C++ libcurl check header before downloading body](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/10775205/c-libcurl-check-header-before-downloading-body)

Answer (score 0):

If just checking the modified date is enough for you, libcurl has a direct support for this - refer to [CURLOPT_TIMEVALUE](https://curl.haxx.se/libcurl/c/CURLOPT_TIMEVALUE.html). There's an example code too:

```
CURL *curl = curl_easy_init();
if(curl) {
  curl_easy_setopt(curl, CURLOPT_URL, "http://example.com");

  /* January 1, 2020 is 1577833200 */
  curl_easy_setopt(curl, CURLOPT_TIMEVALUE, 1577833200L);

  /* If-Modified-Since the above time stamp */
  curl_easy_setopt(curl, CURLOPT_TIMECONDITION, CURL_TIMECOND_IFMODSINCE);

  /* Perform the request */
  curl_easy_perform(curl);
}
```